Optimal Choice of Attributes for Tables in KDB
Consider a table of ohlcv data:
date       ticker    open   close  high   low  volume exch       time                         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2024.05.02 NVDA 173    173.7  173.95 173    870      NASDAQ      2024.05.02D09:15:00.000000000
2024.05.02 NVDA 173.85 173    173.85 173    2290     NASDAQ      2024.05.02D09:16:00.000000000
2024.05.02 NVDA 173.55 173.5  173.55 173.25 382      NASDAQ      2024.05.02D09:17:00.000000000
2024.05.02 NVDA 173.5  173.5  173.5  173.5  10       NASDAQ      2024.05.02D09:18:00.000000000
2024.05.02 NVDA 173.65 173.05 173.65 173.05 435      NASDAQ      2024.05.02D09:19:00.000000000
2024.05.02 NVDA 173.1  172.9  173.1  172.9  1902     NASDAQ      2024.05.02D09:20:00.000000000
2024.05.02 NVDA 172.6  172.45 172.6  172.05 824      NASDAQ      2024.05.02D09:21:00.000000000

and it's sorted on both ticker and time via
ohlcv: `ticker`time xasc ohlcv;

yielding
q)meta ohlcv
c     | t f a
------| -----
date  | d    
ticker| s   s
open  | f    
close | f    
high  | f    
low   | f    
volume| f 
exch  | s    
time  | p 

Clearly from the above, only ticker is sorted, but time is not. However, from the data one also observes that the table is both partitioned and grouped on the ticker column which leads me to my question.
Which of these attributes do I choose to set? And how about the time column? I suppose it's application dependent. If so, what's the best practice?

Some documentation available on the subject:
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/set-attribute/
https://code.kx.com/q4m3/8_Tables/#88-attributes
https://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/table-attributes
There is no one answer for which is best but generally speaking in my experience:
On Disk: p#, u#, s#, g# in order of effectiveness
In mem: s#, p#, u#, g# (though it doesn't really matter for anything below 1m rows/items)
A few things to note:

you can have attributes on more than one column, the most common on-disk combination being p# and g#.
you can have data sorted on time within each ticker (as per your example). It won't show the s# attribute on the time column since it's not sorted on time in an overall sense. Nevertheless for temporal joins like as-of join and window join the logic assumes and behaves as though there is a sorted attribute on the time.
put the p# on the column which is most likely to be the second where filter after the date filter

The common practice for your ohlcv table - assuming you're writing it to disk - would be:

partitioned by date (so where date= will be the first clause)
p# on ticker (assuming ticker= is the next most likely clause)
time sorted within each ticker (i.e.  `ticker`time xasc table before writing it)
g# on time column perhaps - this would allow for faster querying across the time dimension (e.g. give me all records at 2024.05.02D09:15). Or alternatively g# on exch if you're likely to want to ask for all records for a given exchange


Thanks for the excellent, and detailed response @terrylynch
